# How to instantiate events parameter of CfnFunction in Python CDK

Tags: python, aws-cdk

The documentation for the `aws_sam.CfnFunction` of the [Python CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_sam/CfnFunction.html) says that the `events=` parameter takes a type of `Mapping[str, EventSourceProperty]`. I am trying to build an API Gateway backed by a CfnFunction, so I am trying to instantiate it as `Mapping[str, ApiEventProperty]`, since from the documentation it appears that `ApiEventProperty` is a type of `EventSourceProperty`.

I tried to use a Python dictionary {"name": `aws_sam.CfnFunction.ApiEventProperty("get", "/path", <api_logical_id>)}`. However, when I do this, the error message says `object reference expected`. So, I also tried to instantiate it as `aws_core.CfnMapping(self, "name", {"name": aws_sam.CfnFunction.ApiEventProperty("get", "/path", <api_logical_id>)})`. This also doesn't work. I'm not entirely clear what types these functions are expecting, as the `aws_core.CfnMapping`, seems to take nested `Mapping` types, but it also doesn't seem to accept Python dictionaries, which seems to be the most natural way to represent a mapping.

Has anyone had success instantiating this parameter? If so, how were you able to do so?